# If X is a symmetric Bernoulli, Y random variable. How can I show that X and XY are independent iff Y is symmetric?

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X$ be r.v. with symmetric Bernoulli distribution, i.e: $\mathbb{P}(X=-1)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Let $Y$ be r.v. independent of $X$. Show that $X$ & $XY$ are independent iff $Y$ is symmetric:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y > a) = \mathbb{P}(Y < -a)$$
for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

I've tried to solve the problem considering $X=1$ and $X=-1$, like this:

\begin{align}
P(X=1,XY<a)&=P(X=1,Y<a)\\
    &=P(X=1)P(Y<a)\\
    &=P(X=1)\left[P(Y<a|X=1)P(X=1)+P(Y<a|X=-1)P(X=-1)\right]\\
    &=P(X=1)\left[P(Y<a|X=1)\frac{1}{2}+P(Y>-a|X=-1)\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
    &=P(X=1)\left[P(XY<a)\frac{1}{2}+P(XY<a)\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
    &=P(X=1)P(XY<a)
\end{align}
($X=-1$ is completely analogous)

I´m not so sure if the symmetry of $Y$ is well used in the conditional probabilities, and if I can conclude $P(Y<a|X=1)=P(XY<a)$.
Please tell me if my reasoning is correct, or if there's a different way to do the task.

Comment: I would do it by arguing that $P(Y<a|X=1)=P(Y<a|X=-1)$ (and also equal to $P(Y<a)$)

Comment: Um. That would be $P(XY<a|X=1)=P(XY<a|X=-1)$

Comment: You are right, and I figured a way to continue from that point. But do you think that $P(Y<a|X=1)=P(Y>-a|X=1)$ is correct?

Comment: I’m not sure if “symmetric Bernoulli” is the right name in here, I never heard it called like this. The distribution is named as [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution).